# Matching elements from one data frame to other data frame containing lists and keeping in the results the number of rows from the second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, list, match

I have two data frames (one of them contains lists with different number of elements in each):

```
df_1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2, 5, 6, 7), 2, 2))

list_1 <- list(list('joe'), list('mia'), list(1,2,3), list(1,3), list(2,5,4,8), list(4,5,7,8))

df_2  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(list_1, 2, 3))
```

And I would like to search with df_1[1,1] and df_1[2,1] along the second column of df_2, and with df_1[1,2] and df_1[2,2] along the third column of df_2, as follows:

```
A1 <- grepl(df_1[1,1],unlist(df_2[,2])) 
A2 <- grepl(df_1[2,1],unlist(df_2[,2])) 
A3 <- grepl(df_1[1,2],unlist(df_2[,3])) 
A4 <- grepl(df_1[2,2],unlist(df_2[,3]))
```

(In this case it works well if I don't use 'unlist' but in my real data frame it only works (well, not really though) if I unlist the columns of the second data frame). The result is the following:

A1
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

A2
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

A3
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

A4
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

The problem is that I want to do a cbind with A1, A2, A3 and A4, so their final length should be 2, exactly the number of rows of df_2. The final desired resultat is a 2x2 (2 rows of df_2 and 2 columns tested) data frame like this:

(F T F F F) (F F F F F F F F)

(F F F F F) (F F F F F F T F)

I have tried different modifications but I cannot manage to fix that. Could someone of you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` nested in an `mapply`:

```
m <- mapply(\(i) lapply(df_1[,i], grepl, unlist(df_2[,i + 1])), 1:2)

m
#>      [,1]      [,2]     
#> [1,] logical,5 logical,8
#> [2,] logical,5 logical,8
c(m)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have an aditional question: how can I connect the results from 'm' to 'joe' and 'mia'? In this case A1 and A3 are from 'joe' and A2 and A4 from 'mia'. My df is very big and I got very strange results.

Comment: I don't see how you could connect them that way. `joe` and `mia` are associated with *rows* of `df_2`, but the `grepl` `x` argument is a *column* of `df_2` (e.g., `unlist(df_2[,2])`).

Comment: Ind1 (df_1[1,], 2 and 6 in our case is compared with joe and mina (df_2; '2' against column 1 and '6' against column 2. Ind2 (df_1[2,], 5 and 7 in our case) is compared in the same way. After that I would like to see how many TRUE gets ind1 against joe (1 in our case) and mia (0); and the same with ind2, 0 T against joe and 1 against mia. It is for identification purposes. Anyway thanks a lot for your help @jblood94. Maybe I write another question.